# Implementation of IDictionary<TKey, TValue> being interpreted as Array by MsgPack-cli when unpacking

Tags: c#, .net, msgpack

I'm trying to parse a MessagePack message. When I declare the field in question as a `Dictionary<string, Package>` everything works fine and the message is unpacked as expected. However, when I instead declare the field in question as a custom dictionary implementation, `PackageDictionary`, the MsgPack library tries to deserialize it as an array. I have defined `PackageDictionary` as an `IDictionary<string, Package>`. What is going on? Shouldn't the MsgPack library interpret all `IDictionary` implementations as a dictionary and not an array? What am I doing wrong? Do I need to use a attribute to mark that the field should be deserialized as a dictionary?

Here's an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
[DataContract]
public class PackagesMessage
{
    [DataMemeber]
    public PackageDictionary Packages { get; set; }
}

public class PackageDictionary : IDictionary<string, Package> { ... }
```

This is where i get an error message saying "Unpacker is not in the array header at position..."

If instead I switch the Packages type to Dictionary like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class PackagesMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, Package>() Packages { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works fine and the message is correctly deserialized. Any ideas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Update

I found a work around, not ideal, but I am able to parse the field as `PackageDictionary` type if I change the property to `IDictionary<string, Package>`, then set the default collections serializer for `IDictionary<string, Package>` to `PackageDictionary`. This works at the moment because all `IDictionary<string, Package>` fields should be interpretted as a `PackageDictionary` type but I could see this being a problem if I needed a more common `IDictionary` like `IDictionary<string, string>` and if depending on the field the implementations would need to be different. I'm confused on how setting the serialization context to use `PackageDictionary` serializer as the default for `IDictionary` works but it can't figure out that is should use the same serializer when `PackageDictionary` is the actual type of the property. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well then use a Dictionary for the DataContract class. After deserialization map it to the class you want to work with

Comment: And you can check if MessagePack is looking for ISerializable and if then implement that interface on your custom class

Comment: @SirRufo I could deserialize it into a seperate class but the class is actually a lot bigger than what I've shown here. Everything deserializes fine except this one custom dictionary implementation. I don't really what to have 2 classes that are exactly the same except for this one property. As for ISerializable, I don't think MessagePack uses this interface as far as i can tell.

Comment: Following Single-Responsibility-Principle you will have 2 classes, although they seem to be equal, but they are not. One is for the Persistence-Layer and the other for the Application-Layer.